# MongoDb C# driver does not update my inner list

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this method to push new data into NozzleStateList:

```
    public async Task AddNozzleState(NozzleState nozzleState, Guid tankId, Guid gasStationId)
        {
            UpdateDefinition<GasStation> update = Builders<GasStation>.Update.Push("TankList.$[t].NozzleList.$[n].NozzleStateList", nozzleState);


            await _context.GetCollection<GasStation>().UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == gasStationId, update, new UpdateOptions
            {
                ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>{
                    new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("t._id", tankId)),
            new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("n._id", nozzleState.NozzleId))
                }
            });
        }
```

and the collection it is supposed to be pushed to is this:
[image]
the AddNozzleState method runs without error but does not save anything.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I changed my approach and used JsonArrayFilterDefinition and this code works:

```
public async Task AddNozzleState(NozzleState nozzleState, Guid tankId, Guid gasStationId)
        {
            UpdateDefinition<GasStation> update = Builders<GasStation>.Update.Push("TankList.$[t].NozzleList.$[n].NozzleStateList", nozzleState);


            await _context.GetCollection<GasStation>().UpdateOneAsync(x => x.Id == gasStationId, update, new UpdateOptions
            {
                ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>{
                    new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<Tank>("{'t._id': { $eq : UUID(\""+ tankId +"\")} }"),
                    new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<Nozzle>("{'n._id': { $eq : UUID(\""+ nozzleState.NozzleId+"\")}}")
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Just a heads up but the {$eq: } element is not needed you can directly pass the UUID on the other side of your property.